# AWS Permissions issue on exporing data to a CSV file from Maria DB table

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Our MariaDB RDS system is hosted on AWS and I am trying to export a table data into a csv file using the below SQL, but getting the Access denied error.

```
mysql> SELECT *
    -> INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/products.csv'
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    -> ENCLOSED BY '"'
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> FROM tree_users limit 1 ;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'master'@'%' (using password: YES)
mysql>
```

Below are the permission data from the "mysql.user" table

```
User,     File_priv, Grant_priv, Super_priv
rdsadmin     Y          Y           Y
master       N          Y           N
```

I am newbie to AWS, please guide me where can I change the permission so the export option query would work correctly. Thanks in advance and any help is appreciated......

Answer (score 1):

We cannot export the data directly on AWS system as we do not have access to their system so we need to use a different approach to export the data.

```
mysql -umaster -p -hxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com dbname -e "select concat(field1,',',field2,',',field3) FROM table" > data.csv
```